# How to Transpose only two cell for every row into a new Column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I  have downloaded a series of dataset from http://data.un.org/. When open for example the Dataset of Population i have this situation:

```
Region/Country/Area |   Colonna1 |  Year |  Series |    Value |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
380 Italy   2005    Population mid-year estimates (millions)    58.81
380 Italy   2005    Population mid-year estimates for males (millions)  28.61
380 Italy   2005    Population mid-year estimates for females (millions)    30.2
380 Italy   2005    Sex ratio (males per 100 females)   94.8
380 Italy   2005    Population aged 0 to 14 years old (percentage)  14.1
380 Italy   2005    Population aged 60+ years old (percentage)  25.1
380 Italy   2005    Population density  199.9
380 Italy   2010    Population mid-year estimates (millions)    59.73
380 Italy   2010    Population mid-year estimates for males (millions)  29.02
380 Italy   2010    Population mid-year estimates for females (millions)    30.71
380 Italy   2010    Sex ratio (males per 100 females)   94.5
380 Italy   2010    Population aged 0 to 14 years old (percentage)  14
380 Italy   2010    Population aged 60+ years old (percentage)  26.9
380 Italy   2010    Population density  203.1
```

But i want transform the table in this way:

```
Region/Country/Area |   Colonna1 | Value | Population mid-year estimates (millions) | Population mid-year estimates for males (millions) |
Population mid-year estimates for females (millions) | ... 
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    380 |Italy  |2005   |58.81  |28.61  |30.2     | ...
    380 Italy   |2010   |       |       |         |
```

Comment: Try a pivot table.

Comment: I have tried but in the result compare a sum of value that i don't want.

Comment: worked for me: https://imgur.com/LH5vNJ2

Comment: How to avoid the sum of field ? And i notice that you have a column with filter date. If i put this in the Filter area it create a separate row. Can explain me please ?

Comment: I have no filters.  I put Region, colonna1 and year in rows.  I put Series in Columns and Value in values.  Then I removed subtotals and grand totals.  Changed the layout to tabular and repeated the items for every row.

Comment: Yes, it work I forgot to thank you :)